# Не работают медиа запросы. Голый css

Tags: css

Делаю адаптацию для сайта, но не работают медиа запросы, поискал информацию в интернете, ничего не нашел.
код css

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> вставил
```

код css

```
#login_placeII
{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 2em;
    width: 25%;
    height: 10em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-top: -14em;
}

#login_place
{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 2em;
    width: 25%;
    height: 10em;
    margin-top: 5%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 40%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) and (min-width: 350px)
{

    #login_placeII
   {
        background-color: white;
        padding: 2em;
        width: 25%;
        height: 10em;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #login_place
    {
        background-color: white;
        padding: 2em;
        width: 25%;
        height: 10em;
        margin-top: 5%;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

}
```

html код

```
<center>
    <div id="login_text">Sign Up</div>
    <form method="POST" id="login_place">
            <div class="login_logpass">username</div>
            <input type="" name="" class="login_input"><br>
            <div class="login_logpass">password</div>
            <input type="password" name="" class="login_input">
            <button id="login_button">Sign up</button>
    </form>
</center>
<center>
    <div id="login_placeII">
        <div id="login_textII"></div>
        <div id="login_text_signup">Already have an account?? Sign In!</div>
        <a href="login"><button id="login_signin">Sign in</button></a>
    </div>

</center>
```

В чем проблема? Заранее огромное спасибо

Comment: А что работать должно? У вас CSS в медиазапросе дублирует дефолтное состояние. Поставьте background:black в медизапросе и увидите, что в промежутке 350-700px все работает.

Comment: Не совсем, он сдвигает второй блок с текстом вниз под первый блок, если вы сидите с телефона

Comment: Сравните построчно, вы прописали те же стили, как и сказал xydope. Вероятно, у вас проблема в понимании работы стилей. То, что вы внутри `@media` не прописали `margin-right: 40%;` - не значит что он исчезнет, т.к. применён вне `@media` и действует по умолчанию

Comment: Попробовал внутри @media изменить цвета фона, да, действительно, проблема в моем понимание работы стилей, извините что отнял ваше время, огромное спасибо

Comment: Стили переделывайте, вы элементы позиционируете через margin - это очень плохая практика. Используйте float/flex/grid

Comment: хорошо, большое спасибо за совет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны прописывать css для сброса каких либо параметров в media запросах.

В вашем случае вы не можете понять почему не исчезают margin-left и margin-right - и проблема в том что вы не указываете их сброс в медиа запросах.

Ваш CSS должен быть вот таким:

```js
    #login_placeII {
        background-color: white;
        padding: 2em;
        width: 25%;
        height: 10em;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-left: 35%;
        margin-top: -14em;
    }

    #login_place {
        background-color: white;
        padding: 2em;
        width: 25%;
        height: 10em;
        margin-top: 5%;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-right: 40%;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 700px) and (min-width: 350px) {

        #login_placeII {
            margin-left: auto; /* это сбросит отступ */
        }

        #login_place {
            margin-right: auto; /* это сбросит отступ */
        }

    }
```